# Import external package docstrings using sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I would like to import an external app docstring using `Sphinx`. More specifically, I'd like to do something like this:

```
.. autoclass:: django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this is in fact possible. Just need to add `django` or any sphinx documented module to your path at `conf.py`, doing something like this:

```
# docs/conf.py
import environ

env = environ.Env()
sys.path.append(env('PATH'))
```